# How to reinstall Python but keep all existing libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to reinstall Python and keep all existing modules and setups?

The problem is with SQlite3 on Google App Engine, Ubuntu, Python 2.7.

When i try to run the script, I get:

```
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

The sqlite3 is properly installed, when I import it on Python console, it doesn't raise an error. But when I run the development server with GAE - I get this error.

Suggestions from other stackoverflow questions are to rebuild the python.

I have never done it, and I'm afraid of messing up some other modules/configurations - therefore asking if there is any safe way to ensure it won't break.

Comment: On Windows? Why don't you just run the installer setup again?

Comment: Why do you need to reinstall? It might be easier to fix your problem than to reset your environment.

Answer (score 7):

If you installed your python via pip, you can use `pip freeze > reqs.txt` to get a list of installed packages.

After you reinstalled the python, run `pip install -r reqs.txt` to install the modules.